# How to check a date in classic asp

Tags: datetime, asp-classic

I have a variable **last_login** and want to output a message if the last login was *yesterday*, *today* or elsewise output the date. The last two cases are clear but how can I check if a given date in classic asp was **yesterday**?

I'm blockheaded right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dateadd("d",-1,currentDate)

http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/func_dateadd.asp